# How can I unset the session when a page is closed?

Tags: php, javascript, session

How can I unset the `SESSION` when I close the page by clicking [x] (not `onunload`).
I want to insert when opening the page and when closing, but I don't want to insert when refreshing.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["visits"]))
    $_SESSION["visits"] = 0;
    $_SESSION["visits"] = $_SESSION["visits"] + 1;
if ($_SESSION["visits"] > 1){echo "You hit the refresh button!";}
else{
    mysql_query(
        "INSERT INTO najd_visit( visit_userId, visit_staticId, visit_page,
            visit_enterTime)VALUES ('$userId', '$Sid', '$title', '$date') ");
    echo "This is my site";
    //unset($_SESSION["visits"]);
}
```

Comment: You can't easily do that, the client would have to callback the server to do that. Why not have a session timeout?

Comment: I want to insert when open the page and when close , but I dont want to insert when refresh

Comment: Isnt every open window going to be closed eventually anyway?

Answer (score 0):

By setting the session cookie's expiration to 0, it will automatically be cleared when the browser closes completely.

It's not quite what you were looking for (it only clears the session if the entire browser is closed), but it should be good enough.

Comment: try to [free your session cache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-cache-expire.php)